# function to returns the nearest element of array to an integer

Tags: c#, arrays, function

I want to make a function that gives an array returns the nearest element to a number.

here is some examples:

```cs
int[] arr = new int[] {12, 48, 50, 100};
my_function(1, arr); // returns 12.
my_function(40, arr); // returns 48.
my_function(49, arr); // returns 50; in two element with equal distance, returns greater number
my_function(70, arr); // returns 50.
my_function(10005, arr); // returns 100.
```

Sorry, I have no idea about how to write this function.

Comment: Is the _arr_ array always ordered?

Comment: @Steve is that important?

Comment: What happens when two elements are at the same distance? As in your example `my_function(49, arr)`? Why should it return 50 and not 48?

Comment: @KlausGütter the answer is the bigger number

Comment: Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: If the array is guaranteed to be sorted you can use `Array.BinarySearch` to find the index of a match or the index of the first value that is larger and then you can check whether that number or the one before is closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution without using `System.Linq` and with `O(n)` complexity. You just go through array in loop and find a number with minimal difference, `abs <= diff` condition allows you to return the latest number (`50` for `49` instead of `48`) in sorted array. If difference equals `0`, it means that you find the exact number

```cs
var arr = new[] { 12, 48, 50, 100 };

int nearest = GetNearest(1, arr);
nearest = GetNearest(40, arr);
nearest = GetNearest(49, arr);
nearest = GetNearest(70, arr);
nearest = GetNearest(1005, arr);

int GetNearest(int number, int[] array)
{
    int diff = int.MaxValue;
    int result = 0;
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        var abs = Math.Abs(item - number);
        if (abs == 0)
        {
            result = item;
            break;
        }

        if (abs <= diff)
        {
            diff = abs;
            result = item;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You could exit early if abs is 0

Comment: Yes, it makes sense

Comment: I want to set different values for arr, when I call function

Comment: @A.L. you can easily pass it to method, I've updated an answer

Comment: Should be noted that this only works on the 49 case because the list is already sorted.  It is possible to make this work for unsorted arrays by taking the sign of the difference into account.

Answer (score 4):

```cs
private int GetNearest(int[] array,int number)
{
    return array.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - number)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If you want to be sure that the larger number is before smaller number when the absolute difference is the same, add `.ThenByDescending(a => a)` after `OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - number))`

```cs
private int GetNearest(int[] array,int number)
{
    return array.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - number)).ThenByDescending(a => a).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: @Pavel yes, using `Min` would be better.

Comment: I get an error about `OrderBy`: `int[] doesn't contain a definition for 'OrderBy'` .

Comment: @A.L. add `using System.Linq;` namespace

Comment: Uhm, this doesn't give the expected result for _my_function(49, arr);_ 50 is expected but it returns 48

Comment: @Steve If you want it to return the greater value in case of equality. You can use an `epsilon` value to achieve that in this method. `const double epsilon = 0.1;
      return array.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs( x - number - epsilon)).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Another option is to do `.ThenByDescending(x => x)` after the `OrderBy` to make sure the larger number is before smaller number when the absolute difference is the same.

Answer (score 1):

A different way to get the result expected is to calculate the distance between the value passed and the array elements. Then get the element with the lowest 'distance' and find the matching index in the input array. You need Linq as well here.

```
int Nearest(int value, int[] arr)
{
    var distances = arr.Select(x => Math.Abs(x - value)).ToList();
    int min = distances.Min();

    // Using LastIndexOf is important 
    // if you get two equal distances (I.E. 48/50 and passing 49)
    return arr[distances.LastIndexOf(min)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
public static int my_function(int num, int[] arr)
{
    var minDiff = Math.Abs(arr[0] - num);
    var nearest = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        var diff = Math.Abs(arr[i] - num);
        if (diff <= minDiff)
        {
            minDiff = diff;
            nearest = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return nearest;
}
```

Comment: You could exit early when diff is 0

Comment: @John For which `num` value ??

Comment: What do you mean? If the difference between `arr[I]` and `num` is 0 then clearly you have found the closest number so you don't need to evaluate the rest of the array.

Comment: @John aha, you are right, but I think in these types of questions, the answer should give a solution that works and working on details is not considerable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the array is sorted then you can find the closest value like this in O(log n) time.

```
public int GetNearest(int value, int[] sortedArray)
{
    var index = Array.BinarySearch(sortedArray, value);

    // If we found a match then the closest is equal to the value.
    if(index >= 0) return value;

    // Otherwise it's the bitwise compliment to the index of the value just larger.
    var largerIndex = ~index;

    // If the index is the length of the array then all numbers are smaller, 
    //so take the last.
    if(largerIndex == sortedArray.Length) return sortedArray[arr.Length - 1];

    // If the index is 0 then all numbers are greater so take the first.
    if(largerIndex == 0) return sortedArray[0];

    // Now get the number that is just larger and just smaller and calculate the 
    // difference to each.
    var larger = sortedArray[largerIndex];
    var smaller = sortedArray[largerIndex - 1];
    var largerDiff = larger - value;
    var smallerDiff = value - smaller;

    // If the diff to the smaller number is less then we take the smaller number  
    // otherwise the larger number is closer or the difference is the same in which
    // case we take the larger number.
    return smallerDiff < largerDiff ? smaller : larger;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have approached it this way.

```
private static int nearest(int number, int[] numbers)
{
   int min = numbers[0];
   int max = numbers.OrderByDescending(a => a).FirstOrDefault();

   if (number> max)
   {
       return max;
   }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {

    if (numbers[i]<number && numbers[i+1]>number)
    {
       int lower = Math.Abs(numbers[i])-Math.Abs(number);
       int upper = Math.Abs(numbers[i+1]) - Math.Abs(number);

       if (Math.Abs(upper)>Math.Abs(lower))
       {
         return numbers[i];
       }
       else
       {
         return numbers[i+1];
        }

     }
    }

return min;

}
```